# How to extract messages from the dashboard in Mirth?

Tags: javascript, mirth

How to extract messages from the dashboard in Mirth?

Basically using java script, how would I extract the information from dashboard in Mirth.
For example, I am after extracting the encoded data and ACK back from the destination.

One of the thing I tried was to run the following the postprocessor. But it’s only writing raw message not the encoded.

```
var log1file=D:\TEST\log1.txt;
var ReportBody=(messageObject.getEncodedData());
FileUtil.write(log1file, true, ReportBody);
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
logger.info('start post script');
var status = responseMap.get('Destination Name').getStatus();

if ((status == "ERROR" || status == "FAILURE") )
{
    logger.info("Status = "+status);
    var errormsg = responseMap.get('Destination Name').getMessage();
    logger.info(errormsg);
}

return;
```

`getMessage()` describe `exception(error)` description.

Comment: Can you only pass destinations to `responseMap.get` ? I haven't found any documentation related to this.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to extract messages from the Dashboard.  The dashboard is only showing the stored history from the database it keeps.

If you want to write the encoded data to a log file as the messages are processed, move that code from your post-processor over to a transformer javascript step in the source or in a destination (the encoded data changes from source to destination if you have transformer steps or if you change from HL7 to XML, etc.)

Is it actually creating the file?  You don't have quotes around your file name and the backslashes should be forward slashes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the explanation about the dashboard. When I tried the script in the destination transformer, the file is empty. I get an empty log file. Any more suggestions much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: edited answer.  The code you pasted didn't have single or double quotes around the file name and the backslashes should be forward slashes  `var log1file="D:/TEST/log1.txt";`